# AspNetCore .net 6 on Raspberry PI (latest OS) not rendering deployed site correctly

Tags: .net, linux, raspberry-pi, kestrel-http-server, .net-6.0

I am deploying a test web app to a raspberry pi. However, I am having render issue.

Here is what I see when testing via VS
[image: VS Image]

This is what I see from the deployed code on the PI
[image: Correct Formatting Missing]

As you can see it is not loading the files. In the dev console I see that its 404ing on the files

[image: 404]

The Kestrel service is as follows

[image: Kestel]

Is this to do with it listening on any IP? or because  the root path is not ending at /wwwroot

I tried copying the contents of wwwroot to back a level so it is within /web however, I got the same result

Comment: That's hardly a rendering issue and hardly even related to Raspberry PI. Try to publish your site on your local machine (PC) and see whether it works or not. Looks like you just don't have you static resources where they should be

Comment: @AndrewSilver as I said in my post. Deploying locally works fine (via VS, but it I compile and run then that works as well under a windows env). When it is deployed to a Raspberry PI and run via a kestrel server the rendering issues occurs. So I would say it is a rendering issues and it is related to Raspberry PI as that is what it is occurring on

Comment: Did you try to run deployed app locally on your PC using _Kestrel_? Not in debug in VS, not on IIS Express, not on IIS, but on _Kestrel_?

Comment: @AndrewSilver I run the compiled exe from the build folder for the win version I compiled